# Setting up SharePoint 2016 development / learning environment - Cost effective

Tags: farm-setup

Am wondering what is the best and cost-effective way I can setup a learning / dev environment for SP 2016 or 2013.

Would like to hear what setup you guys have (other than company provided resources).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check following Hardware and software requirements by [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#hwforwebserver) and find your cost effective one!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing this list. Any idea of physical machine requirements if I were to run the first scenario on VM?